# Bootstrap 3 Allow Column to Overflow container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two column bootstrap layout and I would like for the right column to be able to overflow the container. The right column contains lists of potentially long strings, this isn't a problem when the only element within the li is the text, but if I want to do perhaps a button and the text within the li this causes the line to wrap and show the button on one line and the text on another.

Is there a way to allow the column to extend past the container even with multiple elements?

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcyzrder/1/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    This is the left column!
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>List 1!</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>List items may be reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeealllly long, but that's ok!</li>
          <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> But when there are two elements it is a problem ..................................................... I don't want this wrap :(
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the number of Bootstrap columns will determine the width of your container, as well as any nested elements. Therefore, by default, the text is going to wrap.

You could try adding a CSS class that prevents word wrapping, like so:

```
<div class="nowrap">Don't wrap this text.</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.nowrap: {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

However, this may cause layout or overlapping issues as your container widths expand with longer content.

**UPDATE**

Your [later JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcyzrder/5/) from the comments below did not have the same markup as your example HTML in the original post. You neglected to mention that you were using `<button>` tags, which in the current CSS are not inline elements. Given markup like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></button>
  <button>Reeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaallllllllllyyyyyyyyyy</button>
</div>
```

I believe the following CSS will give you the desired effect:

```
.btn-group {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group button: {
  display: inline;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weyvayu5/), forked from yours.

Comment: I've tried nowrap and it hasn't worked. I still get the button on one line, and the text on another.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't seem to reproduce this issue. Can you update your code to show the precise problem that you're having?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it to reflect. It's a problem when I have two buttons, one which is very long.

Comment: Either I'm not understanding the issue, or the JSFiddle still isn't producing it. In the second list item, I see a refresh icon. The next word, "But", does not wrap. The remaining text wraps accordingly when there isn't enough space in the viewport. What's the problem? If it's a wrapping issue after the icon, then please provide the browser/OS in which you're seeing this issue. I'm using Mac/Chrome and it looks fine to me. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must have put the wrong link, here is the updated JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lcyzrder/5/

Comment: That does look like it works, but I can't get it to work in my application. I'll have to work more on it. Thanks for all your help!